# Storage additional on AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I need to free up space on disc on AWS lightsail but I prefer to add storage to increase the limit, somebody knows a easy way to do that? Im not good at coding

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional disks to an Amazon Lightsail instance. (It seems like you cannot *extend* an existing disk.)

The main steps are:

- Select your instance in the Amazon Lightsail console
- In the Storage section, click **Create new disk** and enter details
- In **Attach to an instance**, select your instance
- Login to the instance to format and mount the disk

See:

- [Create and attach additional block storage disks to your Linux-based Lightsail instances | Lightsail Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/create-and-attach-additional-block-storage-disks-linux-unix)
- [Creating and attaching a block storage disk to your Windows Server instance in Amazon Lightsail | Lightsail Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/create-and-attach-additional-block-storage-disks-windows)

Comment: Thank you so much! I read and apply this you comment but at the end I can not mount the disk because there is not enought space.   I created the disk and attached to the instance but I was not able to mount the disk, It does not let me create a mount space :(

Comment: Please Edit your Question to add details of your current situation. Please include what you are doing and what errors are occurring.

Comment: I create a new disk, arrached it to an instance and the when I was to format and mount the disk through SSH, I realize that   appears this:    /dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=1701d228-e1bd-4094-a14c-12345EXAMPLE (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)     which means that my  disk already has a file system   and the most important is that I can not enter in ssh because it says:  DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Comment: That message appears to be related to your boot disk (maybe). This is entering the realm of Linux systems administration rather than being specific to Amazon Lightsail. I suggest you create a new question on https://serverfault.com/ with these new details.

Comment: You're a wise person, is true, the problem was with cron that was creating a lot of files every day and finally got my server full.  This is something the linux system makes on a routine basis.  At the end deleting all this cron files was the problem. Thank you so much to give me advice. :)