# Extend storage AWS lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-lightsail

Is there any way to seamlessly add block storage to a lightsail instance running ubuntu? My root directory is filling up and I need a plan for when it eventually fills up.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it is not possible to *extend* a Lightsail disk.

Instead, you will need to **snapshot** the disk and then launch a new instance using that snapshot, specifying a larger disk size.

See:

- [Storage additional on AWS Lightsail - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68213527/storage-additional-on-aws-lightsail)
- [Amazon Lightsail Instance Resize Instructions – Jozef Jarosciak Blog](https://www.joe0.com/2017/06/17/amazon-lightsail-instance-resize-instructions/)